# Get Category image url in magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, image, thumbnail

Can any body tell me how can we get The Category thumbnail image url and Icon image url to display image on frontend in magento 2.3.2

Comment: On where you want to fetch this images?

Comment: I want to get this into my phtml file. Want to display on some custom page

Answer (score 1):

To get Category Image url:

```
<?php echo $category->getImageUrl(); ?>
```

And use it in `<img>` tag like

```
<img src="<?php  echo $category->getImageUrl(); ?>" />
```

Comment: I want to get only thumbnail image only https://prnt.sc/uzre4p

Answer (score 0):

**[Magento 2.4.x]**

> **You can use the below function to get the category media image URL.**

```
/**
 * @category Msquare
 * @package Msquare_CategoryImageSlider
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */

 ...............................................................
 ...............................................................
 ...............................................................

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Image
 */
protected $categoryImage;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\FileInfo
 */
protected $fileInfo;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory
 */
protected $imageHelperFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository
 */
protected $assetRepository;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository
 */
protected $categoryRepository;

public function __construct(
    ...............................................................
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Image $categoryImage,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\FileInfo $fileInfo,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory $imageHelperFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepository,
    ...............................................................
) {
    ...............................................................
    $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    $this->categoryImage = $categoryImage;
    $this->fileInfo = $fileInfo;
    $this->imageHelperFactory = $imageHelperFactory;
    $this->assetRepository = $assetRepository;
    ...............................................................
}

public function getCategoryImage($categoryData, $attributeCode)
{
    $imageLink = null;
    $fileName = $categoryData->getData($attributeCode);
    if (($fileName) && ($this->fileInfo->isExist($fileName))) {
        $imageLink = $this->categoryImage->getUrl($categoryData, $attributeCode); //get category image
    } else {
        $imageHelper = $this->imageHelperFactory->create();
        $imageLink = $this->assetRepository->getUrl($imageHelper->getPlaceholder('image')); // get default placeholder image
    }

    return $imageLink;
}

public function getCategoryData($categoryId)
{
  return $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
}
```

> **After that you need to call the above function into your related phtml file like  below:**

```
$categoryData = $block->getCategoryData(4);
$categoryImage = $block->getCategoryImage($categoryData, 'image');
```

> **Here you need to add your custom category image attribute code.**